# Is it possible to have dimensions without hierarchies in icCube?

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

Is it possible to have dimension attributes without hierarchies in icCube? In SSAS it is possible.

Comment: What is the use of this ?

Comment: nicer UX. since a hierarchy with one element does not describe a hierarchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In icCube a dimension must contain at least one hierarchy ([www](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/dimensions.php)).